# migration of the databese laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

I have this problem can anyone help me. 
  I create application using laravel 5.3 ,i build databse and configure the file .ENV and database.php 
but when i execute the command of migration show me error as the screenshot show

Create databse in my phpmyadmin[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gZD7.png)

here when i execute the command of migration [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl2Mo.png)

Comment: What kind of problem do you have?

Comment: the error show in the screenshot !

Answer (score 1):

Create database **data** in your **phpmyadmin**

You forgot to write **DB_USERNAME =** in your .env file.

In your case:

```
DB_CONNECTION = mysql
DB_HOST = localhost  //or 127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE = data
DB_USERNAME = root
DB_PASSWORD = your password ...
```

Comment: yes I create the database in my phpmyadmin and configure from the file .env and databse.php

Comment: and what problem?

Comment: you dynamically change screenshots and this little confusing

Comment: You created "data" database, but still have the same error (unknown database)?

Comment: It seems you connect to wrong database, try to change your .env db data

Comment: yes i create the database in my phpmyadmin but still not working !!

Comment: the error show that the databse "data" it's not exist ,but in the reality it's exist in my phpmyadmin
-right now i'm using the mysql command in my terminal"mysql -u root -p"mypassword" and when i'm execute the command "show database"my database "data"it's not existe ,what is this problem !!!

Comment: In what environment do you work? Vagrant, valet or xampp?

Comment: I'm using Xampp

Comment: how can i do to fix it !

Comment: write in your .env after"DB_DATABASE=data"  "DB_USERNAME = root"

Comment: i want to know.when i create database from phpmyadmin it's not working.but when i use the command line mysql it's work !!

Comment: You connect to wrong database in your .env, check your credentials

Comment: Hmm, try DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Whats ten problem??. 
That values are in case laravel don't find anything in. Env. So change directly in the file. Env